# How to pass status_code, error_message in Exception

Tags: python, exception

I am using the following exception:

```
class MyApplicationPaymentError(Exception):
    pass
```

However, I want to be able to pass a status_code and error_message to it. So I can do the following:

```
try:
    payment.validate()
except MyApplicationPaymentError:
    print '!!!', status_code, error_message
```

How would I modify the Exception and then the View code to accomplish the above?

Comment: Take a look to: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> class MyApplicationPaymentError(Exception):
...   def __init__(self, statuscode, errormessage):
...     self.statuscode = statuscode
...     self.errormessage = errormessage
... 
>>> try:
...   raise MyApplicationPaymentError(418, "I'm a Teapot")
... except MyApplicationPaymentError as e:
...   print(e.statuscode, e.errormessage)
... 
418 I'm a Teapot
```